# Build two vectors when iterating once over a iterable

Tags: rust

I have an iterator of enum that has two variants. The iterator can be quite big, so I'd prefer to avoid iterating over it more than once. Is it possible to collect two vectors by iterating over it once?

Let's say I have a vector of numbers that are positive and negative. I'd like to kind-of sort them during iteration, which will result of two vectors - one with positive and other with negative numbers. Here's an example pseudocode:

```rust
let input = vec![1, -2, 4, -5, 3];

let (positive, negative) = input
    .iter()
    .some_magic_that_will_make_two_iterators()
    .collect::<(Vec<_>, Vec<_>)>();

assert_eq!(positive, vec![1, 4, 3]);
assert_eq!(negative, vec![-2, -5])
```

Is there any way to achieve that? I know that I can define `positive` and `negative` first, and just push items during iterating, but that won't be the optimal solution for big collections. In my real case, I expect that there may be around million enums in the initial iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Iterator::partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) maybe?

It's eager so there is no collect step. It also can not `map` the elements when partitioning, so that might not work for your needs: it would work fine for partitioning positive and negative values, but it would not work to partition *and unwrap* two variants of an enum.

> Is there any way to achieve that? I know that I can define positive and negative first, and just push items during iterating, but that won't be the optimal solution for big collections. In my real case, I expect that there may be around million enums in the initial iterable.

I don't see why not, it's pretty much what a partition function will do. And you might be able to size the target collections based on your understanding of the distribution, whereas a partition function would not be.

Comment: Isn't in general using `iter().collect::<Vec<_>>` more efficient than calling `vec.push()` multiple times in loop? If `partition()` does that, then I think it'd be better to just use for loop.

Comment: `Vec` has a specialisation for `collect`, but I don't think it's applicable to `partition`. Similarly other collections will at least try to reserve enough space for the iterator's lower bound (if it has a useful one), but without domain knowledge that's not an option for partitioning. `partition` just calls `Extend::extend_one` on either the "left" or "right" results, and that's just a `push`.

Comment: @Djent Pretty much all of the optimizations in `collect` come from either `size_hint` or from special-casing slice and vec iterators. None of these are applicable when partitioning an iterator, and what you're trying to do is *exactly* what `partition` was meant to do. Even *if* there was some more-optimized method, it would eventually land in the stdlib, so there's no point in trying to write your own.

Comment: @Aplet123 - but if I'd use `filter_map()` on an iterator before `partition()` would result in iterating over the initial iterable twice, right? In that case, using for loop may be actually better, as I need to use `filter_map()` first.

Comment: @Djent no, why would it? `partition()` works on arbitrary iterators, since Rust iterators are not rewindable or restartable it can only iterate once.

Comment: @Djent it's on the nightly build for Rust, but, I'm curious: would `partition_in_place` address your performance concerns?

Comment: @egerhard - I think I'm good with `partition()`. I didn't know that the iterators are not rewindable, and I was thinking that stacking multiple `map()`s, `filter_map()`s will make the iterable to be iterated multiple times.